# Find Value "age" with class name bs4 and Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

HTML:

```
<div class="person" age="52"</div>
```

I want to get the value of age with bs4

I have tried:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml") #source is the page.text
age = soup.find("div", { "class": "person" })["age"]
```

But every time I run this, I end up with a None value as if the element doesn't exist.

Comment: There might be another `div` with a `class` attribute of `person` before this `div`, that doesn't have an `age` attribute.

Comment: i looked, there doesnt seem to be one, and when i use findAll, it returns an empty list @Mahesh